# Embedded 3d graphic engine with supporting Blender models

Tags: c++, 3d, blender

I'm trying to develop desktop application. User can load 3d models from Blender with animation (simple object (move, rotate, etc) animation and NLA tracks) and interact with it (rotate model, zoom, click on different object, run animation).

**Requirements:**

1. Platforms: Windows, Linux.
2. High performance
3. Blender support.
4. Application's language: C++, C#, maybe another.

I know about Blend4Web (low performance for big model) and Ogre3d (tried to export scene from blender but in app see only black screen unfortunately). I will wonder if I miss something usefull.

Comment: I have used wrong close reason. Your _"question"_ is  simply opiniion based.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @AustinMullins I'd guess _"I will wonder if I miss something usefull."_ they meant as a question.

Comment: If so, it's definitely off-topic.

Comment: I'm new in 3d visualization. So I asked community to help find engine for my purposes. If it's off-topic - ok, just close my question.

Comment: @AustinMullins I've been VTC for being off-topic because of ***"... recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource ..."***, but it doesn't matter much, this question is OT.

Answer (score 1):

Most Graphics Libraries can store files in the WaveFront obj format. [libObj](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libobj/) can parse and read this format. You should then be able to upload the models to OpenGL and perform the operations that you require.

Answer (score 1):

For a framework to build your app look at [GameKit](https://github.com/gamekit-developers/gamekit)

> Using Ogre for graphics, Bullet for physics, OpenAL for sound
>   OgreKit is most actively developed
>   Engine is written in C++ and the game logic can be done in C++, Lua scripting or logic bricks
>   Reads all data from Blender .blend files, with future FBX import planned
>   Free from viral licenses: only using components using MIT/BSD/Zlib style licenses
>   CMake cross-platform build system support that works out-of-the-box, see http://cmake.org
>   Gamekit supports Windows and Mac OSX, Linux, Android and iPhone.

While it doesn't directly read blend files [godot](http://www.godotengine.org/) is a graphical game building application with python like scripting, it has a gui toolkit that can be used for non-game applications and they offer a blender addon for collada export that is meant to be better than the official one. Being open source you can also adjust it to your needs.